# How to compare vm Templates between two VMware vsphere environment?

Tags: templates, vmware, vsphere

I'm using two different vsphere environments for deploying my application. I'm using a template of pre-installed RHEL, and from time to time I want to update the template on both environment (usually for security reasons). While I'm updating one template and export-import to the other vsphere.

I tried to find some data to compare the templates (to ensure that I'm really use same one) such a checksum, without success.

To make it difficult my two vsphere are not in the same version, one is 5.1 the other is 5.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can export each template to OVA/OVF. Once this is done, inside the OVA or in the OVF folder there is an .mf file, with SHA1 file hashes for the files that make up the template. You should be able to compare those hashes between the templates and validate templates are identical.

Alternatively, once the OVA files are downloaded, you may choose to compute your own fileshashes based on whatever algorithm you prefer.

You are most likely interested in the vmdk file hashes, as the VMX may be different across different ESX versions. If it is different, you will need to find another way to compare the VMX to ensure the configuration, not just the data are identical.